# Suspected GPU crash

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, microsoft-surface

I've recently purchased a Microsoft Surface Book 3, currently running Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2, with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Max-Q graphics card. I've been quite frustrated with repeated events when the entire screen freezes & becomes unresponsive for a few minutes, although programs like music and voice calls still tend to work fine. I really think that this sort of thing shouldn't be such a recurring problem on a high-end laptop. I have no idea what's causing the issue and I can't reproduce it, but it's happening fairly frequently (the reliability viewer shows it happened 3 times this week). I really think that this sort of thing shouldn't be such a recurring problem on a relatively high-end laptop. I suspect it's a GPU crash of some sort, but I don't have much to base it on.

What exactly may be causing the issue? Is there a way to fix it? I thought I'd ask on this site before going to Microsoft Support and just getting the standard response `sfc /scannow` or using the Surface diagnostic tool or completely reinstalling my OS or something.

I've found the following information in the reliability viewer about a "hardware error" that seems to have coincided with the freeze.

> Problem Event Name: `LiveKernelEvent`
>
> Code: `1a8`
>
> Parameter 1: `8`
>
> Parameter 2: `0`
>
> Parameter 3: `0`
>
> Parameter 4: `0`
>
> OS version: `10_0_19042`
>
> Service Pack: `0_0`
>
> Product: `256_1`
>
> OS Version: `10.0.19042.2.0.0.256.48`
>
> Locale ID: `1033`
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>
> > `WATCHDOG-20201026-0844.dmp`
> >
> > `sysdata.xml`
> >
> > `WERInternalMetadata.xml`
> >
> > `WERInternalRequest.xml`
> >
> > `memory.csv`
> >
> > `sysinfo.txt`

**Update:** I've installed the newest drivers for my card. Freezes still happen (it happened about 3 times today, each with varying lengths), but nothing's showing up in the Reliability Monitor. It happened repeatedly while I was listening to a class on Microsoft Teams call, with YouTube playing some music in the background. The last time it happened, the freeze stopped when I pressed the "detach screen" button on my keyboard.

Comment: Does the freeze last more than a few seconds?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it usually lasts for a disruptive amount of time. The last one, which just happened, lasted about 7 minutes. It was resolved when I detached the screen from the base, then reattached it, then held down the power button (and suddenly the screen came back to life!) Not sure if it's related, but I'm also fairly sure the GPU is in the base of the laptop, so maybe ? I've updated the question to include this detail.

Comment: Are you using the latest [NVIDIA Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)?

Comment: @harrymc According to Windows Update I have the latest drivers. Somehow I can't find my driver version on NVIDIA's website; according to dxdiag, my driver is from `7/12/2020`, version `27.21.14.5177`, main driver: `nvldumdx.dll,nvldumdx.dll,nvldumdx.dll,nvldumdx.dll`

Comment: I think you have driver version 451.77, while the latest is [456.71](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/165685/en-us).

Comment: @harrymc Gotcha. I'll update my drivers and see if the problem still occurs. Thank you.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately, after driver updates, the issue still occurs. It's quite problematic and interrupts my workflow on pretty a daily basis.

Comment: It's interesting. I've been having freezes also, although much shorter. In my case, the solution was to go back to driver version [451.67](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/162105/), and the freezes have disappeared.